# org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property (hibernate+postgres)

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate

I'm using hibernate 5.3.11 with SpringDataJpa and PostgreSQL and I get "org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property [packagename.ClassB.classA]" when trying to update a complex entity ClassC.

- ClassC is @OneToMany with ClassA
- ClassA is @OneToOne with ClassB.
- All entities have links to each other before calling update method.
- ClassC is a parent entity and cascades to ClassA, which cascades to ClassB.
- The issue seems to be related only to A<->B relationship.
- show-sql tells me that ClassA persists fine, but seems like for some reason it looses link to ClassB somewhere in hibernate.
- Persisting entity for the first time works fine. The error only comes on update. And I don't even update existing entities of ClassB and ClassA, I replace them with new ones.

**Relationship:**

[image: relationship]

**ClassB in SQL**:
[image: ClassB in SQL]

**ClassA in SQL**:
[image: ClassA in SQL]

**Java entities:**

```
@Data
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"classA"})
public class ClassA {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "classC_id")
    private ClassC classC;
    
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "classA", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private ClassB classB;
}
    
@Data
@Entity
public class ClassB {
    
    @Id
    private Long id;
    
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    @MapsId
    private ClassA classA;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short Answer: I used SpringBoot ver.2.1.8. Updating to 2.2.1 helped.
Long answer here [Post-upgrade, @MapsId is throwing an error when saving an existing entity, but otherwise works fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58561156/post-upgrade-mapsid-is-throwing-an-error-when-saving-an-existing-entity-but-o)