# Cascade on bidirectional @OneToOne with @MapsId

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-one

I work on spring boot `2.1.1.RELEASE`, hibernate `5.3.7.FINAL`

Rules are, that user can have no phone (`phone` is nullable in `user`) but, phone can't exist without a user (`user` is not null in `phone`).

Entities:

```java
@Entity
public class Phone {
    
   @Id
   private Long id;
    
   @OneToOne
   @MapsId
   @JoinColumn(name = "id")
   private User user;
    
   public Long getId() {
       return id;
   }
   public void setId(final Long id) {
       this.id = id;
   }
    
   public User getUser() {
      return user;
   }
   public void setUser(final User user) {
      this.user = user;
   }
}
        
@Entity
public class User {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long id;
    
   @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
   private Phone phone;
    
   public Long getId() {
       return id;
   }
   public void setId(final Long id) {
       this.id = id;
   }
    
   public Phone getPhone() {
       return phone;
   }
   public void setPhone(final Phone phone) {
       this.phone = phone;
   }
}
```

Controller:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping
public class UserController {
    
   private final UserService userService;
    
   public UserController(final UserService userService) {
       this.userService = userService;
   }
    
   @GetMapping("/demo")
   public void createUserAndAddPhone() {
       final User user = new User();
       userService.save(user);
       final Phone phone = new Phone();
    
       phone.setUser(user);
       user.setPhone(phone);
       userService.update(user);
   }
}
```

Repository:

```java
public interface UserRepository  extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

Serivce:

```java
@Service
public class UserService {
    
   private final UserRepository userRepository;
    
   public UserService(final UserRepository userRepository) {
       this.userRepository = userRepository;
   }
    
   @Transactional
   public void save(final User user) {
       userRepository.save(user);
   }
    
   @Transactional
   public void update(final User user) {
       userRepository.save(user);
   }
}
```

Tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `phone` (
   `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
    
CREATE TABLE `user` (
   `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

application yml:

```
spring:
   datasource:
      url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3308/demo?characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
      username: root
      password: 123456
      driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
   jpa:
      database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
      hibernate:
         ddl-auto: validate
```

pom xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.46</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Call `GET http://localhost:8080/demo` gives me an error:

> org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: attempted to assign id
> from null one-to-one property [com.example.demo.Phone.user]

When I comment out `userService.save(user);`, it works and generates:

```sql
insert into `user` 
values ( )

-- Generated identifier: 13, using strategy: org.hibernate.id.ForeignGenerator
                
insert into `phone` (`id`)  values (?)
-- Binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [13]
```

but if the `user` is persisted and then updated, it doesn't work (raises the above exception)

Comment: Are you sure that you run your code inside a transaction. I tried your mapping and it works fine for me.

Comment: Yes, there is `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` annoation

Comment: Could you please show your `application.properties`

Comment: I added spring part from the file. Is it sufficient ? (there is nothing more than some quartz, and email config so I skipped the rest) I have mysql on docker, thus different port.

Comment: When I changed from `@MapsId` to `@MapsId("id")` I got `org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be 
manually assigned before calling save(): (...).Phone` (if it makes any difference)

Comment: @SternK Do you think it may be a hibernate bug ? [link below] (version matches). You said it worked for you, what hibernate version do you have ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58561156/post-upgrade-mapsid-is-throwing-an-error-when-saving-an-existing-entity-but-o

Comment: Do you have a mapping  exactly as you provide without any inheritance and embedded types?

Comment: Could you please try to remove `@NotNull` from the `Phone.user` , set `ddl-auto: none` and recheck your problem. It would be nice to see the full stacktrace of the exception.

Comment: I tested it with exactly your hibernate version on the pure hibernate project. If there is no success with the problem please share minimal project to reproduce the problem.

Comment: no inheritance and embedded types (they both looks like in my code). Removing `@NotNull` and setting to `none` didn't work for me (did `mvn clean compile` before start to be sure, as I use two annotation processors, but still the same error)

Comment: @SternK I have added all files necessary to reproduce the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, in the end, this is a hibernate bug ([HHH-12436](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12436)).

It is reproducible in a pure hibernate application by the following use case:

```java
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

Transaction tr1 = session.beginTransaction();
User user = new User();
session.persist(user);
tr1.commit();

Transaction tr2 = session.beginTransaction();
Phone newPhone = new Phone();
user.setPhone(newPhone);
newPhone.setUser(user);
session.merge(user);
tr2.commit();

session.close();
```

As you can see from the above link it is fixed in hibernate 5.4 branch.

P.S. I was able to reproduce the problem in the latest 5.3 version (`5.3.18.Final`)